# How can redirect pages from old core PHP site to new Joomla site?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url, joomla, ubuntu

We have our old site into core PHP and we have developed it again into Joomla 1.5 last year (because of some limitations we have to build it into 1.5). Now the problem is the URL of sites changed as we have use SEO URLS on Joomla.

In between we have use .htaccess to redirect user from old URL to new like this

```
Redirect /pages/oldpage.php http://www.mydomain.com/products/category/new_page.html
```

Is this good practice to redirect user to new URL or not?(we have used same server).

One more thing, We have used splash page on our site, and to set up it we have made some changes and because of it one of the important link is not working, and it is

```
http://www.mydomail.com/index.php
```

How can I get rid of it? I have used `DirectoryIndex splash.html home.html index.php` in .htaccess to open splash page first when someone open my site `www.mydomain.com`.

Note: my website hosted on dedicated Ubuntu server.

---

**EDIT:** As mentioned I use Joomla and I have enabled SEF facility into it and it has already written .htaccess as per below (as I do not understand it much).

```
DirectoryIndex splash.html home.html index.php   
 RewriteEngine On

  ########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

Redirect /pages/oldpage.php http://www.mydomain.com/products/category/new_page.html
.....................
.................
```

Comment: You say that `index.php` does not work - what happens exactly?

Comment: It shows 404 page of joomla

Comment: I am rather puzzled by this line: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]` - this would appear to unconditionally rewrite all URLs to `index.php` and return a 403 Forbidden?! I would have expected some `RewriteCond` directives before this?

Comment: Yes there are, I have edited my question for it.

Comment: A silly question, but... presumably `/index.php` does actually exist?

Comment: Yes it is exist

Comment: Is that your entire .htaccess file? There does not appear to be anything in what you have posted that would return a 404 when you access `/index.php` directly, apart from the fact that the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` environment variable might not be set. What do you expect/want to see when someone accesses index.php directly - should they see the splash screen? Or bypass it?

Comment: I have edited it and now it is entire .htaccess file. I expect to see the home page of the site instead of splash page when someone accesses the index.php directly. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this good practice to redirect user to new URL or not?

Yes, you will need to do this if you wish to maintain your search engine ranking and prevent any old links to your site from breaking. However, you need to use a 301 (moved permanently) redirect...

```
Redirect 301 /pages/oldpage.php ....
```

If you omit the status code then a 302 (temporary) redirect will be returned and search engines might not update their links.

---

```
http://www.mydomail.com/index.php    # Returns 404 when accessed directly
```

***(Note: The following is generic code for redirecting from `/index.php` to the bare URL `/`, if `/index.php` is not working (it exists but is returning a 404 when accessed directly) then there is possibly something else amiss that needs to be corrected.)***

Again, you need to 301 redirect from `/index.php` to your domain root (presumably `http://www.mydomain.com` works OK?!). However, this might not be quite so straight forward if you have `DirectoryIndex index.php` as you could create an redirect loop as mod_dir will internally rewrite `/` to `/index.php`. However, this can resolved with mod_rewrite and specifically checking `THE_REQUEST` and only redirecting when it is a request from the client (HTTP) and not an internal rewrite.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

(In fact you should probably be redirecting from any directory index to the bare URL.)

Comment: I would hold off using my code for the minute. If `/index.php` is not working then there is possibly something else amiss. Presumably if you access the domain root (`http://www.mydomain.com/`) then it works OK?

Comment: yes if I access domain root it is working as I have set directory index set to splash.html page, the splash page displayed, but if I write mydomain.com/index.php then it will gives me 404 error

Comment: Hi w3d, is there any suggestion for me? Please help me to get rid of this problem